# how to calculate the probability for having $C\geq13$ points in bridge

Tags: probability

In a 52-card deck, Jack is worth $1$ point, Queen $2$ points, King $3$ points, Ace $4$, and everything else is worth $0$.

How to calculate the probability you have a hand with sum $C\geq13$ points? where one hand is $13$ cards.

Comment: How many cards are a "hand"?

Comment: try to find the integral solutions of $$J+2Q+3K+4A=13, J,Q,K,A\leq4$$

Comment: i was told "this is very easy". I just dont see how you can do it easily. the answer is 28.5%

Comment: @Hamid. A bridge hand has thirteen cards.

Comment: I do not see this as an easy problem, especially you are requiring $\geq 13$ but not exactly $=13$. It boils down to the use of multi-hypergeometric pmf, intelligent counting (enumerating) and efficient programming.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure out an easy way to do it either. One could write a program that, for each possible combination of face cards and aces, found the point count and the number of hands:

```
module myfuns
   implicit none
   integer, parameter :: INT64 = selected_int_kind(18)
   contains
      elemental function choose(N,k)
         integer, intent(IN) :: N,k
         integer(INT64) choose
         integer i
         if(k < 0 .OR. k > N) then
            choose = 0
         else
            choose = 1
            do i = 1, k
               choose = choose*(N+1-i)/i
            end do
         end if
      end function choose
end module myfuns

program bridge
   use myfuns
   implicit none
   integer(INT64) totals(0:40)
   integer i1,i2,i3,i4
   integer PC(4)
   integer(INT64) kount
   totals = 0
   do i1 = 0,4
      do i2 = 0,4
         do i3 = 0,4
            do i4 = 0,4
               PC = [i1,i2,i3,i4]
               kount = sum([(i4*PC(i4),i4=1,4)])
               totals(kount)=totals(kount)+ &
                  product(choose(4,PC))*choose(36,13-sum(PC))
            end do
         end do
      end do
   end do
   write(*,*) 'Probability = ',sum(totals(13:))*1.0d0/sum(totals)
   write(*,'(a)') '$$\begin{array}{cc}Points&Frequency'// &
          '&Points&Frequency\\'
       do i1 = 0, 19
          write(*,'(4(i0,a))') i1,'&',totals(i1),'&',i1+20,'&', &
             totals(i1+20),'\\'
       end do
       write(*,'(2(i0,a))') i1,'&',totals(i1),'& & \\'
       write(*,'(a)') '\end{array}$$'
end program bridge
```

Thus producing a table of frequencies vs. point counts:
$$\begin{array}{cc}Points&Frequency&Points&Frequency\\
0&2310789600&20&4086538404\\
1&5006710800&21&2399507844\\
2&8611542576&22&1333800036\\
3&15636342960&23&710603628\\
4&24419055136&24&354993864\\
5&32933031040&25&167819892\\
6&41619399184&26&74095248\\
7&50979441968&27&31157940\\
8&56466608128&28&11790760\\
9&59413313872&29&4236588\\
10&59723754816&30&1396068\\
11&56799933520&31&388196\\
12&50971682080&32&109156\\
13&43906944752&33&22360\\
14&36153374224&34&4484\\
15&28090962724&35&624\\
16&21024781756&36&60\\
17&14997082848&37&4\\
18&10192504020&38&0\\
19&6579838440&39&0\\
20&4086538404& & \\
\end{array}$$
[Yuck that's ugly] and computed the probability as number of hands with point count $\ge13$ divided by total number of hands to get Probability =   0.267902868132708. Doesn't agree with your number, sorry. Maybe bonus points for distribution contributed to that number?

Comment: Actually you are correct. According to Wikipedia, 26.7% is the right answer. Good job!

Answer (score 1):

Simulation based on a million hands. Two or three place accuracy
for the desired probability. Probability 0.268 is in substantial agreement with Wikipedia and the impressive program (+1) of @user5713492. (Maybe the part that is supposed to be 'easy' is
that the expected count is 10.)

```
deck = c(4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1, rep(0, 36))
m = 10^6; count= numeric(m)
for (i in 1:m) {
  count[i] = sum(sample(deck, 13)) }
mean(count >= 13)
## 0.267509  # aprx P(count >= 13); 0.268343 on second run
mean(count)
## 10.00306  # aprx E(count)
```

For what they may be worth, here are approximate probabilities for various values of the count
encountered in the simulation. Still accurate to 2 or 3 places, but the relative error is very large for
very small probabilities.

```
table(count)/m
count
       0        1        2        3        4        5 
0.003747 0.007838 0.013626 0.024818 0.038611 0.051797 
       6        7        8        9       10       11 
0.065699 0.080542 0.089627 0.092900 0.094288 0.089355 
      12       13       14       15       16       17 
0.079643 0.069020 0.056629 0.044054 0.033169 0.023856 
      18       19       20       21       22       23 
0.015828 0.010513 0.006381 0.003803 0.002156 0.001063 
      24       25       26       27       28       29 
0.000555 0.000287 0.000125 0.000051 0.000013 0.000003 
      30 
0.000003
```